# Paypal payflowlink error

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

I have integrated payflow with hosted checkout pages. After getting the secure token I have redirected to paypal but getting the  'Error: Invalid Merchant or Merchant doesn't exist!'.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Try to reset/save/submit the templates inside manager.paypal.com
- You can try this payflow link demo site http://www.techycommerce.com/payflow_tutorial/payflow_CC_secure.php and see if it works.